# How to know current tab width of terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, tabs

I know [tabs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tabs) command can be used to set the tab width of the terminal, but how can I know current tab width of the terminal (assuming the tabs are equidistant)? I can't find related information in [tabs manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tabs), do I miss something?

Comment: That assumption is not always the case, note.

Comment: Tabs may not be equidistant. Do you want the positions for each tab?

Answer (score 2):

One could use a `tab-width.sh` script like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo -ne 'a\tb'  &&
    echo -ne "\033[6n"            # ask the terminal for the position
read -rs -d\[ _                   # discard the first part of the response
read -rs -dR foo                  # store the position in bash variable 'foo'
foo=$(cut -d";" -f2 <<< "$foo")   # discard row number
printf "\r\e[0K%d\n" $((foo - 2)) # subtract 2 for 'a' and 'b'
```

Adapted from [this answer on
StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8353312/3691891).
Example:

```
$ tabs 10

$ ./tab-width.sh
10
$ tabs 20

$ ./tab-width.sh
20
$ tabs 3

$ ./tab-width.sh
3
```

Use carefully, the script has not been tested thoroughly.  It seems to
work well in most cases although the same value is returned for both 1
and 2:

```
$ tabs 1

$ ./tab-width.sh
2
$ tabs 2

$ ./tab-width.sh
2
```

but one should notice that output returned by `echo -e 'a\tb'` is also the same in both cases.

Comment: Of course, on a real (late model) DEC VT one has the DECRQPSR request and the DECTABSR response.  There are several emulators that implement this, including Christian Parpart's contour and MinTTY.

Comment: wow, that's some black magic. but it does not behave as one would expect in a script.

Comment: How doesn't it?

Comment: To detect 1-width tabs, simply add a tab, like `a\t\tb` then divide by 2 like `(((foo - 2) / 2)`. cos (5-2)/2 = 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The following doesn't actually work as I thought it did. Thank you @4wk_ for point this out in the comments :)

---

I've been using

```bash
echo $'\t' | wc -L

# typical output:
8
```

for this purpose.

- `echo $'\t'` = prints a single tab character
- `wc` = the "word counter" program
- `-L` = aka `--max-line-length`; the switch that tells `wc` to calculate the line length, *with tabs properly expanded*

I've found this method to be quite portable between different TTYs and shells. The only thing I would add to increase portability is simply change the echo to:

```bash
echo -e "\t"
```

but tomato-tomato really.

Comment: Does this expect tabs to be every eight characters? It's not always a valid assumption

Comment: `wc -L` doesn't work under macOS

Comment: This was clever, but wrong: `wc` count what the OS see, not what is displayed to our terminals! So it always say "8", even if I change tabstop size with `tabs -4` (and confirm visually).

Comment: ope, you're right @4wk_!